Blazor/Maui Hybrid using Entra ID
I'm building an app that needs to run on Web, Android and iOS.
I'm hoping to write it most of it in Blazor using a Blazor Class Library hybrid design with Maui like this: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/9.0/MauiBlazorWeb
I also want to use Entra ID so that users can sign in with Google, Facebook etc. Like this: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/9.0/BlazorWebAppEntra
Can anyone tell me how put these two samples together into a basic example? Thanks.

You asked this question 2 days ago.  Please do not post duplicates

I was asked to edit my question so that I wasn't asking for code samples but was instead asking for help. I did this but my question was still rejected so I tried again. My question clearly states "can anyone tell me how to...". I can't believe it's this hard to post a question. Please tell me what I have to do to get help with this issue.

Please read [ask].  Your question still boils down to “please write code for me”.  A much better approach is to show us what you’ve tried and explain the specific problem you’re having.  Also consider that Entrata only has about 500 posts, so SO might not be the best source for help on that topic
